# ExecuteReader requires command to have transaction when connection assigned to command is in pending local transaction

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am getting the above mentioned exception for the following code:-

```
public bool insert(tdata data)
        {
            SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = null;

            try
            {
                int partid = 0, strid = 0;
                var status = 1;

                var load = Convert.ToInt32(data.load);
                var vload = Convert.ToInt32(data.iVerticalLoad);

                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlTransaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();

                //Insert Part into table 1
                string sqlquery = "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlConn, sqlTransaction);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //Get Part IDs
                string sqlquery1 = "";
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery1, sqlConn);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da1.Fill(dt1);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
                {
                    partid = Convert.ToInt32(row["PartID"]);
                }


                //Get STR ID
                string sqlquery2 = "";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery2, sqlConn);
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                da2.Fill(dt2);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    strid = Convert.ToInt32(row["STRID"]);
                }


                //Check whether Type is NULL.
                if(data.type != null)
                {
                    //Insert in table 2
                    string sqlquery4 = "";
                    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sqlquery4, sqlConn, sqlTransaction);
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlTransaction?.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
                

                sqlTransaction.Commit();
                sqlConn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception eI)
            {
                sqlTransaction?.Rollback();
                throw eI;
            }
        }
```

Since, I need to make sure that part is inserted in both table 1 and table 2 or not stored in either, I have kept the transaction commit at last. I have also put sql transaction part of sqlcmd before ExecuteNonQuery. Yet I am getting the exception at *Get Part IDs* section. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

`SqlDataAdapter` uses a `SqlCommand` under the hood, which also needs to be attached to the transaction. You can hook it up using `adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = yourTransaction;`

But in this case, you only want a single row seemingly, so just use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`

Note also:

- Always put `SqlConnection` `SqlCommand` `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlTransaction` in `using`. This ensures they are disposed properly. In the case of a transaction, this also rolls back automatically if you have not committed.
- Do not cache the connection object. Create and dispoe as mentioned.
- Always parameterize your SQL statements. Do not inject data into your queries.
- I strongly suspect this could all have been done in a single batch. But as you haven't show your SQL I can't say.
- bail out on the `null` check at the beginning, to save having to open the connection.

```cs
public bool insert(tdata data)
{
    //Check whether Type is NULL.
    if(data.type != null)
        return false;

    int partid = 0, strid = 0;
    var status = 1;

    var load = Convert.ToInt32(data.load);
    var vload = Convert.ToInt32(data.iVerticalLoad);

    using var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString);
    sqlConn.Open();
    using var sqlTransaction = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();

    //Insert Part into table 1
    const string sqlquery = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlConn, sqlTransaction))
    {
        // add parameters here
        // cmd.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.Whatever, 100).Value = paramValue;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //Get Part IDs
    const string sqlquery1 = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery1, sqlConn, sqlTransaction))
    {
        // add parameters here
        // cmd.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.Whatever, 100).Value = paramValue;
        partid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    //Get STR ID
    const string sqlquery2 = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery2, sqlConn, sqlTransaction))
    {
        // add parameters here
        // cmd.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.Whatever, 100).Value = paramValue;
        strid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    
    //Insert in table 2
    const string sqlquery4 = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery4, sqlConn, sqlTransaction))
    {
        // add parameters here
        // cmd.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.Whatever, 100).Value = paramValue;
        cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    sqlTransaction.Commit();
    return true;
}
```